# How to pass extracted function to custom function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, antd

Imagine this .jsx code:

```
<Form.Item rules={[
    ({getFieldValue}) => ({
        validator: passwordConfirmValidation
    })
]}>
```

How can I pass the extracted function `getFieldValue` (only avaailable inside the Form-Item to my custom function `passwordConfirmValidation`? I want to use this function inside my custom function.

Comment: .bind sets the `this` context to the first argument, and only passed 2nd+ args as extra to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're using antd design components so you can safely create a function outside and then just pass the getFieldValue to the outside function like this:

```
// Return a function to avoid typing errors
const passwordConfirmValidation = (func: Function) => () => {
 const data = func();
 console.log(data);
};

  return (
      <Form.Item
        label="password"
        name="password"
        rules={[
          ({ getFieldValue }) => ({
            validator: passwordConfirmValidation(getFieldValue)
          })
        ]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
  )
```

In that way you will get always the latest values from the input and you can create the logic inside passwordConfirmValidation to handle your validation.

Here's the working code https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd41610-forked-3lwgm

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my case I was forced to use `validator: () => passwordConfirmValidation(getFieldValue)` by my typescript compiler. Maybe you can add a note why this is the case.

Comment: yes you're right, to fix that error you can do it that way or just change the passwordConfirmValidation const to return an inner function:    `const passwordConfirmValidation = (func: Function) => () => {
    const data = func();
    console.log(data);
  };`